# Reading RSA keys from .PEM file to RSA structure in C

Tags: c, openssl, rsa, pem

JKJS

Observations:

Suppose RSA private key is created by following commands:

```
openssl genrsa -out mykey.pem 1024
```

Then, there is no problem reading key from that file in C:

```
RSA *privatekey=NULL;
privatekey=PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(fp,NULL,NULL,NULL);
if(privatekey==NULL)
ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
```

But, if RSA keypair is created by following command:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:1024 -sha1 -keyout mykey.pem -out rootreq.pem
```

Then reading from mykey.pem results in error.
Why?

JKJS
Hardik

Comment: What error are you getting? Also open mykey.pem in any editor - do you see ENCRYPTED in the header?

Comment: 140528560309920:error:0607606B:lib(6):func(118):reason(107):p5_crpt2.c:209: 140528560309920:error:06074078:lib(6):func(116):reason(120):evp_pbe.c:200: 140528560309920:error:23077073:lib(35):func(119):reason(115):p12_decr.c:83: 140528560309920:error:2306A075:lib(35):func(106):reason(117):p12_decr.c:123: 140528560309920:error:0907B00D:lib(9):func(123):reason(13):pem_pkey.c:132: finished: Segmentation fault

Comment: possible duplicate of [openssl reading RSA key from PEM file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658220/openssl-reading-rsa-key-from-pem-file)

Comment: @GregS - you have linked to the current page!!!! It will recurse itself to death.

Comment: @user93353: it is a different page when I click on it.

Comment: PLease answer my question.I am stuck with it.

Comment: You've already accepted an answer!

Comment: This answer solves reading key from unencrypted( means with no password ) files.It doesn't give an answer to files with passphrase.Giving 3rd parameter as a passphrase results in same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 2nd, command, did you give a passphrase? Open the key created by the 2nd command in any editor - do you see ENCRYPTED in the haders?

If yes, then that's why you aren't able to read it using `PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey` because you are passing 3rd param as NULL.

Pass a callback to get a password in the call to `PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey`.

Alternately you can remove the password from the key by using the following command

```
openssl rsa -in mykey.pem -out mykey1.pem.
```

This will ask you for a passphrase - if you give the right passphrase, you will get the key in an unencrypted form in `mykey1.pem`

Comment: Yes.The command is as following: privatekey=PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(fp,NULL,NULL,(void *)password);It is showing same error.

Comment: If the pem key is encrypted with a passphrase, you either need to remove the passphrase or pass the password in the 3rd param to `PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey`

Comment: Then what should I do? Please help me.And by the way, password is 3rd param or 4th param? And, yes, key created by 2nd command is encrypted.

Comment: Thanks. It is working by removing passphrase.But, it is not working by giving parameter.(Even if I don't give parameter passphrase, it asks for passphrase at runtime.But after that same error.)Thanks to user93353.