# failed to read private key from .pem file in c

Tags: security, openssl, rsa

I created mykey.pem using command

`"openssl genrsa -out mykey.pem 1024"`

and then I separate public key using command

`'openssl rsa -in key.pem -pubout -out pubkey.pem'`

I am reading private key using function,

```
PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(fp,NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

But I could not retrieve the private key.

Do i have to get rid of headers like 'Begin RSA private key' and 'End RSA private key'? //Which i tried but didn't work

Do I have to send any other value to the PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey function?

or use some other function to retrieve the private key?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659613/reading-rsa-keys-from-pem-file-to-rsa-structure-in-c According to this thread I do not have to send any other parameter to PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey()

Answer (score 2):

if you are still not able to retrieve the private key using

```
PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey()
```

even after supplying the passphrase, a reason could be that you have not initialised the OpenSSL library properly, try adding

```
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers();
OpenSSL_add_all_digests();
```

before you call

```
PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey()
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to get rid of headers from the file. However, if the file is password protected, you need to pass the password into function PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey.

You can also see PEM_read_PrivateKey. Other functions are listed [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/pem.html).

If the fp points to a file with RSA private key in PEM form and without any password, then it should succeed.